# Intersect Select Statements on Specific Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a table of SalesDetails, looking like this:

```
InvoiceID, LineID, Product

1,1,Apple
1,2,Banana
2,1,Apple
2,2,Mango
3,1,Apple
3,2,Banana
3,3,Mango
```

My requirement is to return rows where an Invoice contained sales of both: Apple AND Banana, but if there are other products on such an invoice, I don't want those.

So the result should be:

```
1,1,Apple
1,2,Banana
3,1,Apple
3,2,Banana
```

I tried the following:

```
Select * from SalesDetails where Product = 'Apple'
Intersect
Select * from SalesDetails where Product = 'Banana'
```

Didn't work, because it seems Intersect needs to match all the columns.

What I'm hoping to do is:

```
Select * from SalesDetails where Product = 'Apple'
Intersect ----On InvoiceID-----
Select * from SalesDetails where Product = 'Banana'
```

Is there a way to do this?

Or do I have to first Intersect on InvoiceIDs only using my criteria, then select the rows of those InvoiceIDs where the criteria is matched again, I.e.:

```
Select * From SalesDetails
Where Product In ('Apple', 'Banana') And InvoiceID In 
  (
  Select InvoiceID from SalesDetails where Product = 'Apple'
  Intersect
  Select InvoiceID from SalesDetails where Product = 'Banana'
  )
```

Which seems somewhat wasteful as it's examining the criteria twice.

Comment: Which version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2014, Developer Edition

Comment: How about `union`? @Xinneh

Comment: @nevra Union would return invoices where Apple was sold, without Banana (or the other way around) on a single invoice, I need to return the rows of invoices where BOTH Apple AND Banana were sold on a single invoice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay this time I've managed to get reuse of the Apple/Banana info by using a CTE.

```
with sd as (
Select * from SalesDetails 
where (Product in ('Apple', 'Banana'))
)
Select * from sd where invoiceid in (Select invoiceid from 
  sd group by invoiceid having Count(distinct product) = 2)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0192b/6)

Comment: I like this method.  However, you should use `in` instead of `or`, and I prefer `exists` to `in` (but I think the latter is a matter of preference).

Comment: I agree that an 'in' is nicer. I didn't think of it until I saved my answer and then saw yours and thought, hmm, yes that's nicer. But I will update mine to use an 'in' instead of an or.

Comment: @LeonBambrick Thanks, this delivers the result, but it's still the same as my last code, which works, but examines the criteria twice. Not that that's an issue, I was just wondering if there was a better way of doing it.

Comment: @Xinneh I've found a way to only state the criteria once... if it helps.

Comment: @LeonBambrick I like it, thanks. I'm going to modify it slightly to support multiple products in the criteria, and then use it. Thank you. Performance wise, it's 1 second faster than my original code,but hey, faster is faster.

Answer (score 3):

Do it with conditional aggregation:

```
select * 
from SalesDetails
where product in ('apple', 'banana') and invoiceid in(
select invoiceid
from SalesDetails
group by invoiceid
having sum(case when product in('apple', 'banana') then 1 else 0 end) >= 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think OP's suggestion is about the best one can do.  The following might be faster, although I expect the difference to be slight and I have not done any benchmarking.

```
Select * From SalesDetails
Where Product ='Apple' And InvoiceID In
(
Select InvoiceID from SalesDetails where Product = 'Banana'
)
union all
select * from SalesDetails
Where Product ='Banana' And InvoiceID In
(
Select InvoiceID from SalesDetails where Product = 'Apple'
)
```

Comment: Works to return the expected results, but takes about 3 times slower. Thanks anyhow, I guess this is as optimized as gets.

Answer (score 3):

A self-join will solve the problem.

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM SalesDetails T1 
INNER JOIN SalesDetails T2 ON T1.InvoiceId = T2.InvoiceId
   AND (T1.Product = 'Apple' AND T2.Product = 'Banana'
     OR T1.Product = 'Banana' AND t2.Product = 'Apple')
```

Comment: `Select *` should be `select T1.*`.

Answer (score 2):

First, you want to `COUNT` the number of rows per `InvoiceID` that matched the criteria `Product = 'Apple' or 'Banana'`. Then do a `SELF-JOIN` and filter the rows such that the `COUNT` must be `>= 2`, or the number of `Product`s in your critera.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0192b/1/0)

```
SELECT sd.*
FROM (
    SELECT InvoiceID, CC = COUNT(*)
    FROM SalesDetails
    WHERE Product IN('Apple', 'Banana')
    GROUP BY InvoiceID
)t
INNER JOIN SalesDetails sd
    ON sd.InvoiceID = t.InvoiceID
WHERE
    t.CC >= 2
    AND sd.Product IN('Apple', 'Banana')
```

Comment: Is it not returning Invoice 3? I thought it is. =)

Comment: Although I am unsure if this is any faster than OP's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Other was is to do `PIVOT` like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [InvoiceID] TINYINT
   ,[LineID] TINYINT
   ,[Product] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([InvoiceID], [LineID], [Product])
VALUES (1,1,'Apple')
      ,(1,2,'Banana')
      ,(2,1,'Apple')
      ,(2,2,'Mango')
      ,(3,1,'Apple')
      ,(3,2,'Banana')
      ,(3,3,'Mango');

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource
PIVOT
(
    MAX([LineID]) FOR [Product] IN ([Apple], [Banana])
) PVT
WHERE [Apple] IS NOT NULL 
    AND [Banana] IS NOT NULL;
```

It will give you the results in this format, but you are able to `UNVPIVOT` them if you want:

[image]

Or you can use `window` function like this:

```
;WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT  *
            ,SUM(1) OVER (PARTITION BY [InvoiceID]) AS [Match]
    FROM @DataSource
    WHERE [Product] = 'Apple' OR [Product] = 'Banana'
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE [Match] =2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method using window functions:

```
select sd.*
from (select sd.*,
             max(case when product = 'Apple' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by invoiceid) as HasApple,
             max(case when product = 'Banana' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by invoiceid) as HasBanana
      from salesdetails sd
     ) sd
where (product = 'Apple' and HasBanana > 0) or
      (product = 'Banana' and HasApple > 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @t table (Id int,val int,name varchar(10))
insert into @t (id,val,name)values
 (1,1,'Apple'),
(1,2,'Banana'),
(2,1,'Apple'),
(2,2,'Mango'),
(3,1,'Apple'),
(3,2,'Banana'),
(3,3,'Mango')
;with cte as (
select ID,val,name,ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY val)RN from @t)
,cte2 AS(
select TOP 1 c.Id,c.val,c.name,C.RN from cte c
WHERE RN = 1
UNION ALL
select  c.Id,c.val,c.name,C.RN from cte c
WHERE c.Id <> c.val)
select Id,val,name from (
select Id,val,name,COUNT(RN)OVER (PARTITION BY Id )R from cte2 )R
WHERE R = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT  *
FROM [dbo].[SalesDetails]
WHERE [Product]='banana')
,cte1
AS
(SELECT  *
FROM [dbo].[SalesDetails]
WHERE [Product]='apple')

SELECT *
FROM cte c INNER JOIN cte1 c1
ON  c.[InvoiceID]=c1.[InvoiceID]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to write the condition once and are sure that each Product will only be once in any Order, you can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT InvoiceID, Product
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceID) matchcount
  FROM SalesDetails
WHERE Product IN ('Apple','Banana') ) WHERE matchcount = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using, inspired by @Leon Bambrick:

(Expanded a little to support multiple products in the criteria)

```
WITH cteUnionBase AS
    (SELECT * FROM SalesDetails
        WHERE Product IN ('Apple Red','Apple Yellow','Apple Green','Banana Small','Banana Large')),
cteBanana AS
    (SELECT * FROM cteUnionBase
        WHERE Product IN ('Banana Small','Banana Large')),
cteApple AS
    (SELECT * FROM cteUnionBase
        WHERE Product IN ('Apple Red','Apple Yellow','Apple Green')),
cteIntersect AS
    (
    SELECT InvoiceID FROM cteApple
    Intersect
    SELECT InvoiceID FROM cteBanana
    )
SELECT cteUnionBase.* 
FROM cteUnionBase INNER JOIN cteIntersect
                        on cteUnionBase.InvoiceID = cteIntersect.InvoiceID
```